# bootstrap container height 100% does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is as shown below:

xyz.scss

```
.menu-about {
    display: none;
}

header {
    display: none;
}

.container {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#q-nav-about {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4rem;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 3000;
    .q-logo {
        margin-left: 1rem;
        width: 99px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    ul {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .q-nav-about {
        position: relative;
        color: #898989;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: $f3;
        padding: 0rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
    }
    ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .q-nav-work {
        position: relative;
        color: #898989;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: $f3;
        padding: 0rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
    }
    .q-nav-contact {
        position: relative;
        color: #898989;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: $f3;
        padding: 0rem 8rem 0rem 2rem;
    }
}

.r-contact-container {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    background-color: blue;
    .row {
        .no-padding {
            padding: 0 !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
        }
    }
}
```

xyz.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/scottjehl/picturefill/3.0.2/dist/picturefill.js" async></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img class="mob-logo-about" src="../image/logo_logo.svg" alt="New york">
        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
        <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
    </header>

    <div class="menu-about">
        <ul>
            <a href="/template/about-us.html">
                <li>About us</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#work">
                <li>Products</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact-us">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="q-nav-about">
        <img class="q-logo" src="../image/logo_logo.svg" alt="New york">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="q-nav-about " href="/template/xyz.html">xyz</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-work" href="#abx">abx</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="q-nav-contact" href="#lll">lll</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container r-contact-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 no-padding">hdbdasjhdasdhjsda</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">sdcdbcjdhhddahs</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My layout looks as shown below:
[image]

Comment: What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I want to see the whole page covered in blue color rather than this small strip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the below CSS:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Then you can adjust the height of the `r-contact-container`.

```
.r-contact-container {
      margin-top: 4rem;
      width: 100%;
      height: 86% !important;
      background-color: blue;
}
```

This height can be adjusted, I have just used 86%.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use other unit of measure, you can try using:

```
height: 100vh.
```

"100vh" is 100% of height of window screen.

Comment: How is this any different from 100% ?

Comment: Those are 2 different values! 100vh = screen height, 100% = container empty space height